# Unable to make ipa: Archive Failed

Tags: ios, xcode5, ipa

Xcode Project works well in simulator but i am unable to make an ipa.

It showing error while archiving..

Error :`Lexical or Preprocessor issue Classes/ViewControllers/QUProgramDetailsController.h:13:9: 'ProgramDetailsDTO.h' file not found and Archive gets failed`

can any one please help me?

Comment: You have to specify added framework path at build settings> Frame work search paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the `Framework` and all it's `headers` are imported into your project properly.

Also in your `Build Settings` set `YES` to `Always search user paths`, and make sure your User header paths are pointing to the Framework.

Finally, `Build->Clean` and Restart Xcode.